# Perl packages question

Tags: windows, eclipse, perl, activeperl

I'm new to Perl.

I dowloaded a perl application, that has such a line in a source file:

```
 use PWING::Utils::Utils;
```

It imports a file as it seems.

I downloaded a plugin for Eclipse [Perl-Eclipse integration].
When I try to start that file as a perl app, it says it cannot find an imported resource.

Now the question is, what a perl package structure look like?

That line means there must be a catalog structure like this:

```
    PWING - 
          Utils - 
                 Utils.pm ?
```

I see that the app I downloaded does not contain such a structure, so how can and should be started?

Comment: Are you using Windows and ActiveState's ActivePerl, or are you using Linux? What application have you downloaded - `PWING::Utils::Utils` doesn't appear to be a CPAN module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [perlmod](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#Perl-Modules) documentation states

> All Perl module files have the extension `.pm`. The `use` operator assumes this so you don't have to spell out `"Module.pm"` in quotes. This also helps to differentiate new modules from old `.pl` and `.ph` files. Module names are also capitalized unless they're functioning as pragmas; pragmas are in effect compiler directives, and are sometimes called "pragmatic modules" (or even "pragmata" if you're a classicist).
>
> The two statements:
>
> ```
> require SomeModule;
> require "SomeModule.pm";
> ```
>
> differ from each other in two ways. In the first case, any double colons in the module name, such as `Some::Module`, are translated into your system's directory separator, usually "/".
>
> ...
>
> Perl packages may be nested inside other package names, so we can have package names containing `::`. But if we used that package name directly as a filename it would make for unwieldy or impossible filenames on some systems. Therefore, if a module's name is, say, `Text::Soundex`, then its definition is actually found in the library file *Text/Soundex.pm*.

The special [`@INC`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%40INC) array contains directories to be searched for modules:

> #### @INC
>
> The array `@INC` contains the list of places that the `do EXPR`, `require`, or `use` constructs look for their library files. It initially consists of the arguments to any `-I` command-line switches, followed by the default Perl library, probably `/usr/local/lib/perl`, followed by `"."`, to represent the current directory. (`"."` will not be appended if taint checks are enabled, either by `-T` or by `-t`.) If you need to modify this at runtime, you should use the `use lib` pragma to get the machine-dependent library properly loaded also:
>
> ```
> use lib '/mypath/libdir/';
> use SomeMod;
> ```

Answer (score 0):

On a Unix system this file would be found in a directory of the form

```
 lib/PWING/Utils/Utils.pm
```

but the problem is detecting where the top level directory 'lib' might be.

If the module is installed on your system it will be put into a place where Perl can find it.